# Prediction interval for summed dependent variable from multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, prediction-interval

I have performed a multiple linear regression to forecast 12-month sales from 6-month values (for various predictors) per customer. I obtained y-values per customer and respectively summed the predicted and actual y-values per month to obtain the total sales per month. Is it possible to calculate a prediction interval for the summed y-variable?